# Excel VBA macro to filter

Tags: excel, filter, vba

My excel data look like this. I have two column, A and B.

A  |  B

Aaron | a,b,c

Mark  |  b,c,d

Neil  | a,b,d,e

Tess | c,d,e

When i use auto-filter of excel, the list of possible value for filter is **a,b,c** , **b,c,d** , **a,b,d,e** , and **c,d,e**. This is not what i want. I want to filter the data separately by **a** by **b** by **c** by **d** by **e**.

To make things clear, i need to implement a new filter function. When I click a filter button, filter list containing **select all**, **a**, **b**, **c**, **d** and **e** will be display. When I checked **a**, rows that contains **a** in column B will be display. In this case, row 1 and 3 (Aaron and Neil).

I need a macro to help me with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see [ask] to get an idea of what questions to ask and how.

Comment: spread your letters across multiple columns <- that would be the easiest approach

Answer (score 1):

Click the filter button, then go to column B an select the option Text Filter and then Contains, write which what you want to see (a, b, c, d or e) press OK and it will show any row that has that value you entered.

Hope it helps,
Bruno

PS: you can enter multiple values e.g a in the first line then select the option and the from the list again Contains and enter the next one, and it will show all that have a and b, if you select or you get all that have either a or b.